# cannot get an export to update in connected module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

So i'm working on this app where I need to get a query from a url, then save it to a variable, and export it to use in another module. I'll attach my code. I'm thinking i need to create the variable, and then change the value from inside the router function. But for some reason, when I do that, the value never changes. It only exports the original value from the module. Here's my code from the connected.js file.

```
var tools = require('../tools/tools.js')
var https = require('https')
var url = require('url')
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var invoiceNumberQuery = 0


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var token = tools.getToken(req.session)
  var invoiceNumber = req.query.invoice;
  invoiceNumberQuery = invoiceNumber;
  if(!token) return res.redirect('/')

  // Don't call OpenID if we didn't request OpenID scopes
  if(!tools.containsOpenId()) return res.render('connected')
  // Call OpenID endpoint
  // (this example uses the raw `https` npm module)
  // (see api_call.js for example using helper `request` npm module)
  var options = token.sign(url.parse(tools.openid_uri))
  var request = https.request(options, (response) => {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rawData = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('OpenID response: ' + rawData)
      try {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData)
        res.render('connected', parsedData)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        res.render('connected')
      }
    });

  });
  request.end();

  request.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e)
    res.send(e)
  })

 
})


module.exports = {
  router:router,
  invoiceNumberQuery:invoiceNumberQuery
  }
```

and then I need to access the invoiceNumberQuery variable from my apiCall.js file. I'm getting the export and import correctly, but it's staying at 0 Here's my apiCall.js code

```
var tools = require('../tools/tools.js')
var config = require('../config.json')
var request = require('request')
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

var number = 0

function invoiceNumber(){
  var connected = require('./connected.js')
  number = connected.invoiceNumberQuery
  console.log(connected.invoiceNumberQuery)
}

/** /api_call **/
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var token = tools.getToken(req.session)
  if(!token) return res.json({error: 'Not authorized'})
  if(!req.session.realmId) return res.json({
    error: 'No realm ID.  QBO calls only work if the accounting scope was passed!'
  })
  
  // Set up API call (with OAuth2 accessToken)
  invoiceNumber()
  var url = config.api_uri + req.session.realmId + "/query?query=select * from Invoice where docNumber = " + "'" + number + "'" + "&minorversion=59"
  console.log(url);
  var requestObj = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.accessToken,
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  // Make API call
  request(requestObj, function (err, response) {
    // Check if 401 response was returned - refresh tokens if so!
    tools.checkForUnauthorized(req, requestObj, err, response).then(function ({err, response}) {
      if(err || response.statusCode != 200) {
        return res.json({error: err, statusCode: response.statusCode})
      }

      // API Call was a success!
      res.json(JSON.parse(response.body))
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.json(err)
    })
  })
})

/** /api_call/revoke **/
router.get('/revoke', function (req, res) {
  var token = tools.getToken(req.session)
  if(!token) return res.json({error: 'Not authorized'})

  var url = tools.revoke_uri
  request({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + tools.basicAuth,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'token': token.accessToken
    })
  }, function (err, response, body) {
    if(err || response.statusCode != 200) {
      return res.json({error: err, statusCode: response.statusCode})
    }
    tools.clearToken(req.session)
    res.json({response: "Revoke successful"})
  })
})

/** /api_call/refresh **/
// Note: typical use case would be to refresh the tokens internally (not an API call)
// We recommend refreshing upon receiving a 401 Unauthorized response from Intuit.
// A working example of this can be seen above: `/api_call`
router.get('/refresh', function (req, res) {
  var token = tools.getToken(req.session)
  if(!token) return res.json({error: 'Not authorized'})

  tools.refreshTokens(req.session).then(function(newToken) {
    // We have new tokens!
    res.json({
      accessToken: newToken.accessToken,
      refreshToken: newToken.refreshToken
    })
  }, function(err) {
    // Did we try to call refresh on an old token?
    console.log(err)
    res.json(err)
  })
})


module.exports = router
```